# How to pass an image to a model for classification after the model has been created in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have created the model using Tensorflow

```
Initialized
Minibatch loss at step 0 : 3.51275
Minibatch accuracy: 6.2%
Validation accuracy: 12.8%
Minibatch loss at step 50 : 1.48703
Minibatch accuracy: 43.8%
Validation accuracy: 50.4%
Minibatch loss at step 100 : 1.04377
Minibatch accuracy: 68.8%
Validation accuracy: 67.4%
Minibatch loss at step 150 : 0.601682
Minibatch accuracy: 68.8%
Validation accuracy: 73.0%
Minibatch loss at step 200 : 0.898649
Minibatch accuracy: 75.0%
Validation accuracy: 77.8%
Minibatch loss at step 250 : 1.3637
Minibatch accuracy: 56.2%
Validation accuracy: 75.4%
Minibatch loss at step 300 : 1.41968
Minibatch accuracy: 62.5%
Validation accuracy: 76.0%
Minibatch loss at step 350 : 0.300648
Minibatch accuracy: 81.2%
Validation accuracy: 80.2%
Minibatch loss at step 400 : 1.32092
Minibatch accuracy: 56.2%
Validation accuracy: 80.4%
Minibatch loss at step 450 : 0.556701
Minibatch accuracy: 81.2%
Validation accuracy: 79.4%
Minibatch loss at step 500 : 1.65595
Minibatch accuracy: 43.8%
Validation accuracy: 79.6%
Minibatch loss at step 550 : 1.06995
Minibatch accuracy: 75.0%
Validation accuracy: 81.2%
Minibatch loss at step 600 : 0.223684
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Validation accuracy: 82.3%
Minibatch loss at step 650 : 0.619602
Minibatch accuracy: 87.5%
Validation accuracy: 81.8%
Minibatch loss at step 700 : 0.812091
Minibatch accuracy: 75.0%
Validation accuracy: 82.4%
Minibatch loss at step 750 : 0.276302
Minibatch accuracy: 87.5%
Validation accuracy: 82.3%
Minibatch loss at step 800 : 0.450241
Minibatch accuracy: 81.2%
Validation accuracy: 82.3%
Minibatch loss at step 850 : 0.137139
Minibatch accuracy: 93.8%
Validation accuracy: 82.3%
Minibatch loss at step 900 : 0.52664
Minibatch accuracy: 75.0%
Validation accuracy: 82.2%
Minibatch loss at step 950 : 0.623835
Minibatch accuracy: 87.5%
Validation accuracy: 82.1%
Minibatch loss at step 1000 : 0.243114
Minibatch accuracy: 93.8%
Validation accuracy: 82.9%
Test accuracy: 90.0%
```

This is the accuracy that i am getting after all the iterations are done . I want to save this model so that i can pass a random image and display what my model outputs(classify) given the image .

In caffe we used to create .caffemodel file and then used to pass an image in the command line and used to display the first 5 probable objects that the images is most likely to be , I want to perform a similar thing in Tensorflow but don't know as how to do so.

Any help would be appreciated .

**EDIT**

After the suggestion from mrry i tried looking for the tf.train.saver() obejct as how it work.

This is what is written in the website for storing variables:

```
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.Variable(..., name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(..., name="v2")
...
# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, save the
# variables to disk.

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.
  ..
  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

**For restoring :**

```
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.Variable(..., name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(..., name="v2")
...
# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
# do some work with the model.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  # Do some work with the model
  ...
```

How can i pass my image to the model now ? , It's written in the comment that do some work with the model but exactly how should i pass my image to the model .

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse your trained network for evaluation, using TensorFlow's **feed** mechanism. Typically you will have a tensor called `input` that contains a batch of images and serves as the input to the first layer of your model. Let's also assume that you have a tensor called `logits` that is the output of the final layer of your network (before it is passed to the loss function).

You can get the top-five most probable classes by passing the `logits` to a [`tf.nn.softmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax) op followed by a [`tf.nn.top_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#top_k) op. The resulting program will look like the following:

```
input = ...  # batch_size x height x width x channels tensor
# [...rest of network defined as a function of `input`...]
logits = ...

predictions = tf.nn.top_k(tf.nn.softmax(logits), k=5)

eval_image = ...  # 1 x height x width x channels NumPy array.
                  # NOTE: you may need to reshape this to match `input`.

predicted_classes = sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={input: eval_image})
print predicted_classes
```

Comment: thanks for answering , Actually i was working with the tensorflow assignment (4_convolutions.ipynb) . I understood a bit of it but i am still confused as how the above answer will work . Do i need to train my model again every time after i restart my system? . The data present in the variables will be lost once i restart my system and thus how can we reuse the model ??

Comment: You can use a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) object to save the contents of the variables and restore them into another model.

Comment: i have edited the question , So please could you answer for the same , it would be a great help to me learning Tensorflow .